# Windows 2003 Standard X64 Remote Desktop

Tags: rdp

Have an issue with a Windows 2003 Standard X64 host.  I have enabled remote desktop, I am part of the administrators group and am unable to remote into the machine from my Windows 7 X64 bit desktop.  I check the windows 2003 server host to see if 3389 is up and listening and the odd thing is I dont see it @ all.  This server is running with service pack 2, just cant put my finger on whats causing the issue.  I have tried connecting from a 32bit Windows XP machine as well and same problem occurs.

http://imagebin.ca/img/zdqvKX.png

Comment: is Terminal Services service started at all?

Comment: Yes. Check the pictures that he posted.

Comment: duhaas, did you ever get your answer? There are a lot of nice responses here but no accepted answers and very few upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not even seeing 3389 open, then something in the system is wrong with RDP.  I would try re-applying Service Pack 2 to see if that fixes whatever is wrong with the Terminal Services service.

Do you have anti-virus on the machine that might have "cleaned up" some files it shouldn't have?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any group policy or registry tweaks that might have changed the default port for terminal services? Check the following registry key:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
```

By default it's a REG_DWORD value set to D3D in hex, which is 3389 in decimal.

Comment: yeah, everything is fine there, its just the weirdest thing, cant say I know where to start looking:
http://imagebin.ca/img/CD0qLpeX.png

Comment: Do you have a hardware firewall blocking traffic between the machines?  Or a software firewall on either side?

Comment: nothing site in between the network FW wise.  arrgghhhhh, its just so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Windows Firewall, make sure that Remote Desktop is enabled (Right click on "My Computer" > Properties > Remote Tab).

Comment: checked that, i dont have the firewall turned on:
http://imagebin.ca/img/q8MNGO.png

Answer (score 0):

- Check the server's event logs for pertinent errors
- Try to connect to the server but make sure that no drives, sounds or anything is brought over from the connecting client. Also do not connect in full screen mode.
- Restart the Terminal Services service just for luls and try some more.
- Try remoting into the console session

Also, would you mind listing the applications that are running on that server? BackupExec, perchance?